# How can I retrieve the data from this async function and use it in my JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, jsx

I want to make a simple page which retrieves weather data, in React.js because I recently just started learning it.
During coding I created this async function which retrieves data from a weather API, but I can't seem to get the results out of this function and actually use them inside my JSX.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import './DataHolder.css';

const DataHolder = () => {

    const [countryInput, setCountryInput] = useState('');
    const [cityInput, setCityInput] = useState('');

    const API = 'API KEY'

    async function fetcher() {
        const weather = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityInput},${countryInput}&appid=${API}`);
        const weatherData = await weather.json();
        const resName = weatherData.name;
        const countryName = weatherData.sys.country
        const resHumidity = weatherData.main.humidity;
        const resTemp = weatherData.main.temp;
        const condition = weatherData.weather.main;
        return resName, resHumidity, resTemp, condition, countryName

    }

    const onChangeCountry = (event) => {
        setCountryInput(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
    }
    const onChangeCity = (event) => {
        setCityInput(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div className="data__main">
            <div className="data__inputs">
                <input type="text" placeholder="City name" onChange={onChangeCity} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Country name" onChange={onChangeCountry} />
                <Button className="button" variant="contained" onClick={fetcher} >Primary</Button>
                <ul>
                    <li>Location: {/* resName, countryName*/} </li>
                    <li>Humidity:{/* resHumidity */}</li>
                    <li>Temperature: {/* resTemp */}</li>
                    <li>Conditions: {/* condition */}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default DataHolder;
```

I tried using .then on the fetcher() function and return the result there but it won't work. I also tried doing a similar thing,inside the onClick property of the button,whenever I call the function by pressing the button but that won't work either.

I don't really know what else I could for this so any kind of help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `resName, resHumidity, resTemp, condition, countryName` data once it is fetched? You likely should save it into state so the UI can rerender with the fetched weather data.

Comment: @DrewReese YES that was it. How could I not think of that. I thank you so much, stupid me...

Comment: I was about to provide an answer but the question was closed. I voted to reopen as the provided "duplicate" is about fetching data when the component mounts, not as a response to a user clicking a button. Sounds like you are on it though. :)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your help and input :D